# Python - Benchmarking Disk - Write exactly x bytes in a file

Tags: python, file, byte, benchmarking, disk

I am trying to benchmark my Hard drive, this is to say calculate its latency (ms) and throughput (MB/s).
To do that, I want to measure the execution time of the function f.write of Python.
What I need is to write exactly x bytes to my files.
I understand that I need to open my file using

```
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
```

Then what I do is

```
for i in range(blocksize)
    f.write(b'\xff')
```

Howewer, the results I obtain for the throughput (MB/s) is way too low. The latency looks correct. So what I deduced is that when I do the previous lines, I am actually writing more than one byte to the file, I am writing a string containing one byte ...
I know that object don't really have size in Python, but is there a way to fix this problem ?

**EDIT**
Ok here is the new code, now the results are unexplicably too high ! The limit in writing for my disk should be 100MB/s, but I have results ten time faster. What's wrong ?
import sys
import time

```
f = open("test.txt",'wb+')

def file_write_seq_access(blocksize):
    chunk = b'\xff'*4000
    for i in range(blocksize//4000):
        f.write(chunk)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    file_write_seq_access(int(sys.argv[1]))
    stop_time = time.time()
    diff = stop_time - start_time 
    print diff, "s"
    print (int(sys.argv[1])/diff),"B/s"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, Python isn't fast enough for this kind of byte-by-byte writing, and the file buffering and similar adds too much overhead.

What you should do is chunk the operation:

```
import sys

blocksize = int(sys.argv[1])

chunk = b'\xff'*10000
with open("file.file", "wb") as f:
    for _ in range(blocksize // 10000):
        f.write(chunk)
```

Possibly using `PyPy` should give a further (very small, possibly negative) speed-up.

Note that the OS will interfere with timings here, so there's going to be *a lot* of variance. Using C might end up even faster.

---

After doing some timings, this matches `dd` for speed, so you're not going to be getting any faster.

Comment: What did you do your timings with ? time.time() ?

Comment: You might want to make your chucks equal in size to the filesystems block size, if you know it. If you're not sure how big, 4kb is often a good guess.

Comment: I am running linux in a VM, so is the filesystems block size the one of windows or the one of linux ? Do you think that running in a VM can have side-effects on the accuracy of my timings ?

Comment: @JahMyst `time python3/python2/pypy/pypy3 wite_blocks.py 100000000`.

Comment: Please see the edited code, now my results are too high and I can't understand why. I timed with time.time(). Same results with timeit module ...

Comment: @JahMyst I suggest you use the code I gave you :P. You're not closing the file because your file is global. Using `with`  fixes this. This matters because of local caches which aren't getting flushed.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to make results fine is using the low-level I/O for minimizing call time overhead and flushing the buffers, otherwise your writes could become buffered somewhere(for example by OS You use).

```
from time import perf_counter as time

def write_test(file, block_size, blocks_count):
    f = os.open(file, os.O_CREAT|os.O_WRONLY, 0o777) # low-level I/O

    took = []
    for i in range(blocks_count):
        buff = os.urandom(block_size) # get random bytes
        start = time()
        os.write(f, buff)
        os.fsync(f) # force write to disk
        t = time() - start
        took.append(t)

    os.close(f)
    return took
```

That code is a part of my hobby project -- a simplistic tool in Python to benchmark HDDs and SSDs. It is completely open-source and now in alpha stage, though you already could use it, and if interested, participate in development. Hope you'll find some good ideas or maybe even provide yours.
Here's the link: https://github.com/thodnev/MonkeyTest